# How to set the name of a snapshot file

Tags: camera, java-me, snapshot

I am developing a J2ME application to run on my W595s Sony Ericsson mobile phone.
My application uses the JSR 135 Mobile Media API and the JSR 234 Advanced Multimedia Supplements API.

My application displays a Form.
The camera video is displayed in a Form's item.
The Form has a command.
The application takes a snapshot when the user activates the command.
The snapshot file is saved to the Picture directory on the memory stick.

Here is the Form's commandAction event listener :

```
public void commandAction(Command arg0, Displayable arg1) {

    m_snapshotControl.setDirectory("e:/Picture");
    m_snapshotControl.setFilePrefix("AC");
    m_snapshotControl.setFileSuffix(".JPG");

    int[]resolutions = m_cameraControl.getSupportedStillResolutions();
    int maxValue = (resolutions.length / 2) - 1;
    m_cameraControl.setStillResolution(maxValue);

    m_snapshotControl.start(1);
}
```

I ran my application 2 times.
The Picture directory did not contain any snapshot file before the first run.
I did the following actions during each run :

1. I activated the command
2. I answered yes to the following rights requesting dialogs :

   1. Allow the application to read user data ?
   2. Allow the application to write user data ?
   3. Allow the application to read user data ?
   4. Allow the application to write user data ?
   5. Allow the application to shoot with the camera ?
   6. Allow the application to read user data ?
   7. Allow the application to write user data ?

The AC0000.jpg snapshot file was created after the first run.
The AC0000.jpg picture file was replaced after the second run.

I do not want my application to replace snapshots taken during past runs.
How can I set the name of a snapshot file before taking the snapshot ?
Is it possible to set the string in between the prefix and the suffix ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a PlayerListener to the SnapshotControl's Player.
My playerUpdate method renames the created Snapshot file when the SHOOTING_STOPPED event occurs.
The new name is made up of the current date and time's parts.
The format of the new name is YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg.
Here is the playerUpdate method :

```
public void playerUpdate(Player arg0, String arg1, Object arg2) {

    if (arg1.equalsIgnoreCase(SnapshotControl.SHOOTING_STOPPED)) {

        FileConnection fconn = null;
        try {
            fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///e:/Picture/" + (String)arg2);

            Date now = new Date();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(now);

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            month++;
            if (month < 10) {
                buffer.append(0);
            }
            buffer.append(month);

            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (day < 10) {
                buffer.append(0);
            }
            buffer.append(day);

            buffer.append("_");

            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (hour < 10) {
                buffer.append(0);
            }
            buffer.append(hour);

            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if (minute < 10) {
                buffer.append(0);
            }
            buffer.append(minute);

            int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            if (second < 10) {
                buffer.append(0);
            }
            buffer.append(second);

            buffer.append(".jpg");

            fconn.rename(buffer.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fconn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried on this particular range of phone but how about this:

```
private int iSnapshotCounter = 0;

public void commandAction(Command arg0, Displayable arg1) {

    m_snapshotControl.setDirectory("e:/Picture");
    m_snapshotControl.setFilePrefix("AC");
    m_snapshotControl.setFileSuffix( (++iSnapshotCounter) + ".JPG");

    int[]resolutions = m_cameraControl.getSupportedStillResolutions();
    int maxValue = (resolutions.length / 2) - 1;
    m_cameraControl.setStillResolution(maxValue);

    m_snapshotControl.start(1);
}
```

If that works, you can then decide to include the date and time (say, to the second) in the file name.

Of course, if setFileSuffix() won't allow you to specify more than a file extension, you can try to use the same trick on the prefix string.

You may also need to use JSR-75 to figure out what files already exist in the folder.